# Monodromy representation of branched covers

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

From Hilden-Montesinos theorem, we know that every $3$-Manifold can be constructed as an irregular dihedral 3-fold cover of $S^3$ i.e. there is a represented Knot $K$ such that
$
\omega: \pi_1(S^3 - K) \twoheadrightarrow D_3
$ and $M = M(K, \omega)$.

two Questions:

1. Is $\pi_1(M) = ker(\omega)$ (ref. to Fox "covering Spaces with singularities" §7)?
2. Is $D_3$ the monodromy representation of $\pi_1(S^3 - L)$?

all answers, further questions, references or ideas are welcome :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please don't post several questions as if it was a single question.